# How to implement two-finger tap gesture in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any standard/documented ways to implement two-finger tap event in WP7?

If not, is it possible to code manually using the manipulation events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no two-finger tap event for WP7. And, yes, you can build this yourself. I would recommend looking at how the gesture services handle low-level manipulation events to ouput gestures, [as described in this blog](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-GestureService-in-depth--key-concepts-and-API).

Comment: Okay, then it may not be a good idea to implement this gesture as it isn't documented/supported. I'll check out the link. Thank you!